# Date of the latest modified entity in Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

Say we have an audited entity such as:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Person {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

}
```

and after storing/updating few hundreds of records, I need to get the latest modified entity given a set of `id`s. Given the Envers table logic, it would be as simple as:

```
SELECT MAX(R.REVTSTMP) FROM PERSON_AUD P JOIN REVINFO R ON P.REV = R.REV
WHERE P.ID IN (12, 35, 143, 151, 165, 188, 234, 251);
```

but I can't find a way in to get this info through the JPA or Envers API. Note that I'm looking for an "Enver's way" to do this, trying to avoid native SQL (plus the audit tables are stored in a separate catalog from the entities' one).

Comment: Now I'm fetching all entities and calculate the latest revision date with a stream on the list, but it is highly inefficient since I need to load all entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this through the `AuditQuery` extensions:

```
Object[] results = (Object[]) AuditReaderFactory.get( entityManager )
    .createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity( YourEntity.class, false, false )
    .add( AuditEntity.revisionNumber().in( idsList ) )
    .addOrder( AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc() )
    .setMaxResults( 1 )       
    .getSingleResult();

// Object[0] = YourEntity instance
// Object[1] = The RevisionEntity instance
// Object[2] = RevisionType enum value
```

We don't currently expose a `AuditEntity.revisionTimestamp()` property accessor, so you'd have to fetch the value directly from the `Object[1]` revision entity instance.